# MFI - scaling pos and neg money flow

Tags: pine-script

CODE

```
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mfipos = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
mfineg = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)

_rsi(mfipos, mfineg) =>
    if mfipos == 0
        100
    if mfineg == 0
        0
    100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + mfipos / mfineg))
mf = _rsi(mfipos, mfineg)

plot(mfipos, color=#FF7000, linewidth=2, title='MFI pos')
plot(mfineg, color=#0088FA, linewidth=2, title='MFI neg')
```

MFI is bounded.
Pos and Neg money flow plot do not plot following price graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Money Flow Index is a bounded function from 0 to 100.  In order to properly have the Positive and Negative money flow be plotted as I wanted, I needed to normalize the min and max values.

Results:
[image: Pos and Neg money flow plotted]

```
//Normal MFI calculation
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mfiPositive = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
mfiNegative = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)

//MFI variables to normalize data to be plotted
mfiLow = lowest(length)
mfiHigh = highest(length)
min_mfiPos = lowest(mfiPositive, length)
min_mfiNeg = lowest(mfiNegative, length)
max_mfiPos = highest(mfiPositive, length)
max_mfiNeg = highest(mfiNegative, length)

mfiPosNorm = mfiHigh + (mfiPositive - min_mfiPos) * (mfiHigh - mfiLow) / (max_mfiPos - min_mfiPos)
mfiNegNorm = mfiHigh + (mfiNegative - min_mfiNeg) * (mfiHigh - mfiLow) / (max_mfiNeg - min_mfiNeg)
_rsi(mfiPositive, mfiNegative) =>
    if mfiNegative == 0
        100
    if mfiPositive == 0
        0
    100 - (100 / (1.0 + mfiPositive / mfiNegative))
mf = _rsi(mfiPositive, mfiNegative)
plot(mfiPosNorm, color=colorNavy, linewidth=2, title='MFI Positive Money Flow')
plot(mfiNegNorm, color=colorFuchsia, linewidth=2, title='MFI Negative Money Flow')
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `scale` parameter of the [study()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study) function for that.
It saves you the trouble of normalizing.

Excerpt from the [study()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_study) function in the reference manual:

> ***scale (const integer)** price scale that the indicator should be
> attached to. Possible values are: scale.right, scale.left, scale.none.
> Value scale.none can be applied only in combination with
> 'overlay=true' setting. If omitted, using scale from main series.*

Example with `scale.left`

```
//@version=4
study("Test", shorttitle="TST", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mfiSlow = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
mfiFast = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)

_rsi(mfiSlow, mfiFast) =>
    if mfiFast == 0
        100
    if mfiSlow == 0
        0
    100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + mfiSlow / mfiFast))
mf = _rsi(mfiSlow, mfiFast)

plot(mfiSlow, color=#FF7000, linewidth=2, title='MFI Slow')
plot(mfiFast, color=#0088FA, linewidth=2, title='MFI Fast')
```

Which yields

[image: scale.left example]

Using `scale.none` would yield this

[image]

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure what is different on my end but I have tried using the scale.left function as you mentioned.  But, I do not get the same results as you do above.
Instead my price graph is tiny and the mfi graph ranges from 0-500 on the left scale.

Comment: Take off the indicator from the chart, and then put it back on. That should work.

Comment: Okay, just would like to share that I had tried using the scale.left like you suggest prior to deciding to seek out help.
Remove and readding my script has resolved my issue.  Noted and thank you very much.

Comment: I have updated my original post.  Looks like mfi and the other graphs im plotting may not be compatible to plot with each other??
my ema, vama, and vwap are now smushed in scale.

Comment: Apparently you're using a `stragegy()` instead of a `study()`. You didn't mention that at first. Could you please update your question and add the complete script that you have? That'll make things easier to investigate.

Comment: Would you like me to convert it to a study?  I wasn't aware that I should expect different graph behavior based on study or strategy.

Comment: Up to you. Depends on wether you want to use what you're making as a `study` or a `stragegy`.

Comment: So the plan is to use it as both, a study and a strategy.  From what you're telling me, a study will produce different results than a strategy?  Im confused as to why I would have needed to mention that in the beginning.  I've gotten the impression that the graph information would be different given your concerned about mentioning it.
Can you explain in detail why they'd be different?  I'd like to avoid frustration in the future if possible.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced they're different, but you seem to have different results. Will be able to see when you post complete code.